Can I put pocket-hole screws in the edge of board?
I want to fix a wobbly chair with some pocket-hole screws, and I'm wondering if it's reasonable to put one through the edge of a board (first image below), rather than on the face of the board (second image below). I can't put them on the inside face of the board where they'd be hidden, so if I could put one on the edge it would be less visible than on the outside face of the chair.
If putting the pocket holes through the edge is reasonable, I was planning to do one on the top edge and bottom edge. One issue though is that the face of the board is 2+" thick. Assuming this is a good idea, how should I choose the right screw length?



Is that a butt joint or is there anything like a mortise/tenon there?

@AloysiusDefenestrate no there’s no mortise/tenon. there were two dowels but one is broken

If there are dowels, it would seem that they're going to be right where the pocket screws are going to go. I'd re-think using pocket screws here and look into replacing/re-gluing the dowels.

mobeets - Check out the pictures in the just added question https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/15432/what-option-to-i-have-for-backing-for-a-dining-chair-as-shown-in-the-pictures, specifically, it has pocket holes between the sides and the back.


I'm wondering if it's reasonable to put one through the edge of a board (first image below),

Yes it's reasonable in theory. Sometimes pocket-hole screws are installed there for various reasons, including your case here where once face of the 'pocket board' is not accessible and the other is a show surface.
However, the previous joint solution here of dowels complicates things. I believe we can see that the screw will transect the dowel at top (top of the image) and because of symmetry it may be exactly the same for the screw going into the opposite edge. This could considerably undermine max strength (but see last point).

I was planning to do one on the top edge and bottom edge.

If it were viable for this situation that would be highly advisable and because the two screws would go into the leg at opposing angles you get a dovetail-like hold, infinitely stronger than if the two screws are parallel as in standard orientation for pocket-hole screws in such a joint.

Assuming this is a good idea, how should I choose the right screw length?

This is really a separate query and should ideally have its own Question but in short the rule of thumb for screws is use one as long as is reasonable for the application. And where strength is a factor, as long as possible, or as thick as possible, or both.
On the plus side here, this unusual location for the pocket-hole screws means you can go much longer than you would otherwise, where longer screw choices would eventually risk the tip of the screws poking through one face of the leg. But instead your screws will angle into a nearly unlimited amount of wood real estate in the vertical axis of the leg, so can be very very much longer than you'd be using otherwise.
The purpose-made panhead screws for use with Kreg jigs are not cheap at the longest lengths, and have limited potential for future use. So perhaps it would be a better choice to go with a different screw (such as a modern construction screw, which has guaranteed future uses). If necessary add a small washer to spread the load within the pocket holes.
Debatably better, repair the existing joint
As a general statement, it's better to repair chairs with breaks such as this by repairing the original joinery than by using screws (of any type and in any orientation).
This will involve:

partial disassembly of the chair;
cleanup of the joint surfaces, including the dowel holes (which may involve re-drilling to a slightly larger diameter);
replacement of both dowels;
re-glueing and holding under clamp pressure until the glue has set.

You'll need a number of clamps for this, not just one, of sufficient reach to span the dimensions of the chair. White or yellow glue, or epoxy, a drill and a range of bits.
You could also take the opportunity to install a third dowel in the middle if you wanted to. Although, if well-glued and clamped, the existing joint is likely perfectly adequate, the extra dowel would substantially strengthen the joint (possibly adding more than 50% extra).

In this instance neither top, bottom nor sides are end grain.  Assuming also there is some sort of seat cushion which would cover the top pocket screw, a  repair with pocket screws shouldn't be noticeable.  I'd hesitate to add glue to the repair.  It's not going to help.  Before repairing this side, check the other side of the chair. It might be a good time to do a similar service on the other side. That other side may not look broken today but, if one side is like this, it's doubtful the other side is in mint condition.  While performing the repair, I'd suggest holding the two pieces in place with a clamp going from the chair front to the point immediately behind the chair where you are attaching the side to the back.  Personally I'd use a pipe clamp.
A close inspection of the picture shows you have access to the Kreg brand of pocket hole jig.  It's probably best to follow their recomendations for length of screws, position of pocket holes, depth of pocket holes etc.

Thanks for the vote of confidence that going in on the top would be fine, as well as the suggestion about using a pipe clamp! The reason I asked about the length of screws is that this jig only has screw lengths for up to 1.5", but as you might be able to tell from the photo, this wood is more like 2.5". But if I'm doing one on top and bottom, maybe I should treat the thickness as 2.5/2 = 1.25"?

Uh, if you can prep the wood well (not always possible with a repair) adding wood glue always helps. Doesn't matter which combination of side grain and end grain there is, it helps.

To @Graphus comment on glue, my experience with glue on chairs is now quite cautious.  As a young wood worker I too went with the idea of using glue to correct a loose chair joint - sometimes creating a future major repair requirement.  Some glues (hide is an example) can be easily and quickly repaired while typical 'yellow' glue, epoxy glue and ureaformaldehyde do not.

If a chair is being partially reglued, that is only a few joints, some day other joints may fail.  When that happens the first repair might have to be broken in order to disassemble enough for the later repair.  This I've experienced over the years.  Now if the entire chair is being reglued, a modern glue is more likely to be appropriate.  Glue here isn't going to be as effective since it is an end grain situation.

@mobeets suggestion of treating the 2.5 inch thickness like two 1.25 in pieces is a good idea because it will minimize the chance of the top screw colliding with the bottom screw deep in the wood.

@quill, "since it is an end grain situation" It's not. The major 'limb joint' if we can call it that is end grain to long grain. That's completely different to end grain meeting end grain (even in conventional wisdom, which has been challenged recently). The primary glue surfaces are the dowels and their respective holes (as evidenced by some woodworkers, and many factories, choosing to not apply any glue to the flat surfaces or being so slapdash as to apply far too little and then compounding the problem by not applying sufficient clamp pressing along the correct axis).

To replace the broken dowel would require disassembly of the other back rail joint, as well as more woodworking tools and experience.  Adding modern glue to the joint on just one side could prove a hindrance in the future when someone with the additional time, experience and equipment repairs the other side.

Not all old repairs with improper glue amounts, pressure and bad technique are slapdash.  It might be the work of someone without equipment or experience.  I am certain I have made multiple fixes that might look slapdash now but remember, they were done by someone without experience (me) or tools at a time when ARPANET was a concept and resorcinol glue was easy to purchase.

Perhaps there is a glue to consider for chairs, which might one day need to be again be disassembled for repair.  Hide glues would work of course but I see now that plastic resin glue has a warning 'for interior use only', which suggests if a joint were glued with it, it might be possible to disassemble without damaging the wood.  But - that would also allow the possibility of spilled liquids spoiling a joint.
